# Pygame Buttons Softlock computer

Tags: python, pygame

The goal of this project is to have two separate functions, one is for TKinter and uses Radio boxes to define the resolution of the Pygame window. This part works perfectly.

The second part of the program is the Pygame window, in which I want to have 4 boxes appear that are scaled differently according to the size determined by the first section.

When running the code, the program spazzes out, creates a Pygame window and then it is literally impossible to close the program without having to restart you PC. I'm hoping someone can tell me what's going on here and why something isn't working the way I want it to.

***Be careful if you run this code, you might have your pc soft locked.***

```
import pygame, pygame.locals, sys, time


DISPLAYS = [(800, 600), (1024, 786), (1280, 1024), (1600, 1200), (1920, 1080)]

def Test():

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Resolution")
    root.iconbitmap("c:\ResizeImage.ico")
    root.geometry("230x200")


    def CONFIRM(label1): 

        global resolution
        global Selection
        Selection = v.get()

        if Selection == 1:
            resolution = (DISPLAYS[0])
            time.sleep(0.2)
            root.destroy()
                    
        elif Selection == 2:
            resolution = (DISPLAYS[1])
            time.sleep(0.2)
            root.destroy()
            
        elif Selection == 3:
            resolution = (DISPLAYS[2])
            time.sleep(0.2)
            root.destroy()
                    
        elif Selection == 4:
            resolution = (DISPLAYS[3])
            time.sleep(0.2)
            root.destroy()
                    
        elif Selection == 5:
            resolution = (DISPLAYS[4])
            time.sleep(0.2)
            root.destroy()
            
    v = IntVar()

    v.set(1)
    Radio1 = Radiobutton(root, font = "Veranda 10", text = "800 x 600", variable = v, value = 1).pack(anchor = W)
    Radio2 = Radiobutton(root, font = "Veranda 10", text = "1024 x 768", variable = v, value = 2).pack(anchor = W)
    Radio3 = Radiobutton(root, font = "Veranda 10", text = "1280 x 1024", variable = v, value = 3).pack(anchor = W)
    Radio4 = Radiobutton(root, font = "Veranda 10", text = "1600 x 1200", variable = v, value = 4).pack(anchor = W)
    Radio5 = Radiobutton(root, font = "Veranda 10", text = "1920 x 1080", variable = v, value = 5).pack(anchor = W)
    # Gather input from the Radio Buttons and forward it to the CONFIRM function
    label1 = Label(root,text="")
    b = Button(root, font = "Veranda 10", text = "Confirm", command = lambda:CONFIRM(label1))
    b.pack(anchor = SE)
    label1.pack()
    mainloop()

Test()





def MainMenu():

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((resolution))
    screen.fill((100, 100, 100))
    pygame.display.update()
    

    class button():
        def __init__(self, colour, x, y, width, height, text =""):

            self.colour = colour
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.text = text

        def draw(self, screen, outline = None):

            if outline:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height +4), 0)

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

            if self.text != "":
                font = pygame.font.SysFont("segoeuisemibold", 14)
                text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
                screen.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

            def isOver(self, pos):
                if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
                    if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                        return True
                return False                


    def drawItems():
        startButton.draw(screen, (0, 0, 0))
        loadButton.draw(screen, (0, 0, 0))
        optionButton.draw(screen, (0, 0, 0))
        quitButton.draw(screen, (0, 0, 0))
    

    running = True
    while running == True:

        screen.fill((100, 100, 100))
        pygame.display.update()


        if resolution == DISPLAYS[0]:
            startButton = button((0, 0, 0), 100, 150, 200, 50, "Start Simulation")
            loadButton = button((0, 0, 0), 500, 150, 200, 50, "Load Simulation")
            optionButton = button((0, 0, 0), 100, 300, 200, 50, "Options")
            quitButton = button((0, 0, 0), 500, 300, 200, 50, "Quit Program")

        elif resolution == DISPLAYS[1]:
            startButton = button((0, 0, 0), 100, 150, 300, 50, "Start Simulation")
            loadButton = button((0, 0, 0), 624, 150, 300, 50, "Load Simulation")
            optionButton = button((0, 0, 0), 100, 300, 300, 50, "Options")
            quitButton = button((0, 0, 0), 624, 300, 300, 50, "Quit Program")

        elif resolution == DISPLAYS[2]:
            startButton = button((0, 0, 0), 100, 150, 400, 50, "Start Simulation")
            loadButton = button((0, 0, 0), 780, 150, 400, 50, "Load Simulation")
            optionButton = button((0, 0, 0), 100, 300, 400, 50, "Options")
            quitButton = button((0, 0, 0), 780, 300, 400, 50, "Quit Program")

        elif resolution == DISPLAYS[3]:
            startButton = button((0, 0, 0), 100, 150, 500, 50, "Start Simulation")
            loadButton = button((0, 0, 0), 1000, 150, 500, 50, "Load Simulation")
            optionButton = button((0, 0, 0), 100, 300, 500, 50, "Options")
            quitButton = button((0, 0, 0), 1000, 300, 500, 50, "Quit Program")

        elif resolution == DISPLAYS[4]:
            startButton = button((0, 0, 0), 100, 150, 600, 50, "Start Simulation")
            loadButton = button((0, 0, 0), 1220, 150, 600, 50, "Load Simulation")
            optionButton = button((0, 0, 0), 100, 300, 600, 50, "Options")
            quitButton = button((0, 0, 0), 1220, 300, 600, 50, "Quit Program")

        



        for event in pygame.event.get():
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        

        if event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()



MainMenu()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to evaluate if the <kbd>ESC</kbd> is pressed, then you have to test if the `event.type` is `pygame.KEYDOWN` and the `event.key` is `pygame.K_ESCAPE` in the event loop. Take care of the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). I recommend to evaluate the `pygame.QUIT` event, too:

```py
running = True
while running == True:

    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:  
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    # [...]

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```